# AngularJs Error : $http request though defined in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services

I have following code, in which I am calling a service of .php to return data which will later update my model & view. Though, I injected the service name and http in the controller still it gives me error.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
    <button ng-click="changeIt()">Change Name</button>{{name}}
    <script>
        //Module declaration
        var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
        //controller declaration
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, getName, $http){
            $scope.name = "Peter"; 
            $scope.changeIt = function(){
                getName.getTheName()
                    .success(function(data) {
                        $scope.name = data.name;
                    });
            }
        });
        //Service Declaration
        app.service('getName',function(){
            return {
                getTheName: function() {
                    return $http({
                        url: 'hello.php',
                        method: 'Post',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        }
                    });
                },
            }
        });
    </script>
</body> 
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
echo $data=json_encode(array('name'=>'Lara'));
?>
```

Can someone help me out the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to inject it in service too

```
app.service('getName',function($http){
            return {
                getTheName: function() {
                    return $http({
                        url: 'hello.php',
                        method: 'Post',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        }
                    });
                },
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

$http should be defined in the service, not the controller

> app.service('getName',function($http){

Answer (score 1):

You have to inject $http in the service `getName` where you are using it.